# How do I approach the problems asking about uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a set of Ph.d. entrance exams, which are mixed with Analysis and PDE problems. Since I do not have much PDE knowledge at the moment, so I tried to do all the analysis ones. But I am stuck at problems like below

1. Let $X$ be the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$, which are periodic of period $2\pi$. Prove that there exists a unique $u\in X$ such that 
   $$u(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \sin(x) \sin(u(x+\frac{\pi}{3})) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
2. Determine for which values of the parameters $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique continuous function $\psi$ such that 
   $$\psi(t) = \lambda + \mu^2 \int_0^1 s\psi(s)ds + \mu^2 \int_t^1 (t-s)\psi(s) ds$$
   for $0\leq t\leq 1$.

Do I need to use any knowledge from differential equation to solve problems like above? And could you give me a hint on how to approach this type of problems. Thank you very much!

Comment: The solution of the first problem is straigthforward if we do not ask for periodicity (just take $C(\mathbb R)$ with the sup norm and verify that the "obvius" map is 1/2-Lipschitz: then apply Banach-Caccioppoli fixed point theorem). I am wondering what changes adding periodicity condition: the space of continuous periodic functions is still complete under the sup norm hence I think that the same argument applies.

Comment: @Romeo: $\sup$ isn't a norm on $C(\mathbf{R})$, but is a norm on the space of continuous periodic (hence bounded) functions. :)

Comment: @user86418 Oh, sorry: you are perfectly right, I have been stupid. Thanks for pointing it out, now it makes sense.

Comment: I added my solutions, could you help me take a look please, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints. 
For part 1, use Picard-Lindelof or even Banach's fixed point theorem. You need to find a contraction map from $X$ to $X$ itself.

Same hint applies to part 2 as well. If you have not studied these theorems before, then I suggest you to spend some time on them.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.

Comment: I added my solutions, could you help me take a look please, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here are my solutions. Please help me check them, thank you !

1. Define the operator $T:X \rightarrow X$ by
   $$(Tu)(x) = 1+ \frac{1}{2} \sin(x) \sin(u(x+\frac{\pi}{3})),$$
   we see that $T$ is a contraction mapping on $X$ since 
   $$||Tu - Tv||_\infty \leq \frac{1}{2}\bigg|\bigg|\sin(u(x+\frac{\pi}{3}))-\sin(v(x+\frac{\pi}{3}))\bigg|\bigg|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{2}||u-v||_\infty,$$
   since $\sin$ is Lipschitz  continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$.
   By Banach's fixed point theorem, there exists an unique fixed point $u^*$, which gives us the unique solution in $X$.
2. Once again, define an operator from $C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ by 
   $$T\psi(t) = \lambda + \mu^2 \int_0^1 s\psi(s)ds + \mu^2 \int_t^1 (t-s)\psi(s) ds.$$

We choose $\lambda, \mu$ that would make $T$ an contraction mapping.
$$||Tu - Tv|| \leq \mu^2 \bigg|\bigg|\int_t^1 (t-s)[u(s) - v(s)] ds\bigg|\bigg|_\infty \\ \leq \mu^2 ||u-v||_\infty \bigg|\bigg|\int_t^1 (t-s) ds\bigg|\bigg|_\infty = \frac{\mu^2}{2} ||u-v||_\infty.$$

Thus $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $-\sqrt{2} < \mu < \sqrt{2}$ would give us one unique solution by Banach's fixed point theorem.

Comment: It looks good. In general, you also need to make sure that $T$ maps a function from $X$ to another function in $X$ as well, since this is also a necessary condition of the contraction mapping principle. However, that condition is trivial in almost all cases such as this one.  Some professors do find that condition has to be checked and deduct points from you if you left it unchecked, because you think it is too trivial.